The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-nio-3] but has failed to stop it
One of the endpoints in my application calls 3 REST APIs and uses webclient to do so. Everything works fine (getting the response fine from all the 3 endpoints) until I stop the application on my local workspace. I am getting below error when i try to stop the application.
o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [reactor-http-nio-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:883)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:526)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

There are a total of 4 occurrences of the above error which I assume is somehow connected to the REST class I am making using webclient.
This is how one of the endpoint calls looks like:
public Void makeRestCall(Request request) {
URI endpoint = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("url").build().encode().toUri();
        return webClient.post().uri(endpoint).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(request)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                        stringResponse -> stringResponse.bodyToMono(Fault.class).flatMap(
                                pojoResponse -> stringResponse.createException().flatMap(ex -> Mono.error(
                                        new HttpClientErrorException(ex.getStatusCode(), "Field: " + pojoResponse.getErrors().get(0)
                                                .getSourceProperty() + " - Error: " + pojoResponse.getErrors().get(0).getMessageID() )))))
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                        stringResponse -> stringResponse.bodyToMono(Fault.class).flatMap(
                                pojoResponse -> stringResponse.createException().flatMap(ex -> Mono.error(
                                        new HttpClientErrorException(ex.getStatusCode(), pojoResponse.getMessage())))))
                .toBodilessEntity().block().getBody();
    }

I am not sure what could be causing it, is there a way to close the webclient. I assume spring container should be doing it for us. Can someone help?

If your WebClient isn't spring managed it won't be managed. Also it is just a warning not an error you are getting.

@M.Deinum Do you mean it won't be an issue while running in PROD environment? I am little skeptical on that. Also, currently I am creating Autowiring WebClient object inside each of the service class which makes the API call. that could make it spring managed right?

It isn't an issue. Tomcat is only warning you, the reactive library you are using will create a thread and clean it up. So depending on how you create stuff it will or will not do a shutdown. Looking at your code you are also using block() which kind of defeats the purpose of using a reactive client. You might be better of using RestTemplate or the new HttpClient if you need blocking operations anyway.

Also, if you"re actually running webflux, you'd better not use block() and return Mono<Void> instead of Void, to allow webflux perform proper non blocking IO.
